# background menu

Tags: html, css

me tirar uma outra duvida q estou tendo? estou tentando adicionar um background, mas não vai de jeito nenhum a única maneira q apareceu foi criando uma nova div c nome background . olha como está o codigo html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="background">
        <img src="images/fundo.png" alt="Fundo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="LogoTopo"></a>
        </div>
    <div class="links">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">ÍNICIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="md10.html">MD10</a></li>
                <li><a href="eloboost.html">ELOBOOST</a></li>
                <li><a href="duoboost.html">DUOBOOST</a></li>
                <li><a href="vitoria.html">VITÓRIAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="contato.html">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>  
            <ul class="social">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"</i></a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <h1><strong>SECURE ELOBOSTING</strong></h1>
            <p>ELOBOOST // DUOBOOST//MD10</p>

    </header>

    <main>
<section class="destaque">
    <div class="ashe">
        <img src="images/ashe.png" alt="ashetag">
    </div>
        <h2 align="center">SECURE JOB MD10</h2>
            <p align="center">A Secure EloBoosting  está dando para voce uma md10 quase 100% de graça, com descontos de mais de  60%</p>
            <p align="center">De $$120,00 por $$79,99 Por tempo LIMITADO!</p>

</section>

<section class="faq">
        <div class="row">
                    <h2>FAQ</h2>
                    <p>Nós da SecureElobosting percebemos que muitos sites de ELOJOB tiveram seus dados vazados por hackers, muitos clientes tiveram seus emails vazados e consequentemente tiveram suas contas banidas do LEAGUE OF LEGENDS. Foi por isso que nós da SecureJob criamos esse sistema de segurança chamado PMD. Mas afinal, o que é a segurança PMD? PMD significa Pendrive – Messenger- Description. Usamos um messenger criptografado para troca de informações (planos PREMIUM e SJBOOST), pendrive para armazenar o MÍNIMO de suas informações, sem manter NADA online, Sendo assim, se um de nossos boosters ou administradores sofrerem ataques em seus computadores, nenhuma informação sua correrá riscos, tudo estará armazenado em um pendrive, sendo imediatamente deletado após a efetuação do seu elojob.</p>
        </div>
            <a href="#" class="botao.medio"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Continue Lendo</a>        
</section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="logo-rodape">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO RODA PÉ">
            </a>

            <p align="right">Secure Elobosting2017 Todos os direitos Reservados.</p>

            <p align="center">League of legends é uma marca registrada da Riot Games, Inc. Nós não somos de nenhuma forma afiliados, associados ou endossado pela Riot Games, Inc. 
Todos os direitos autoriais, marcas, imagens e marcas de serviço pertencem a seus respectivos proprietários.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

o codigo em css

```
   @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.background
{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../images/fundo1.png);
}



    .logo
{
    float: left;    
    width: 127px;
    height: 106px;
}
.links
{
float: right;   
}
        nav
        ul
        li
{
display: inline-block
}
a
{
text-transform: uppercase   
}

        .social
{

}

h1
{

}
p
{

}
```

e como está aparecendo :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu quero q o menu fique / logo fique sobre essa image, mas estou quewbrando cabeça p fzr isso e vou tentar add esse outro code.

Comment: Não entendi direito. Onde vc gostaria de colocar a imagem originalmente, em qual tag? Vc que usar como <img> ou que usar como Background em algum elemento? Vc quer o loho e o menu antes da imagem ou encima da imagem?